# How do I print out gethostname result in VS 2017 C++ Win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop-application

I'm trying to create a Win32 desktop application that simply print out the hostname of the computer it's run at. I've managed to create such a C++ console application using WSADATA structure and gethostname() that works fine. However, when I try to implement them in my Win32 desktop application, it doesn't work at all.

Looking at the error messages they indicate a TCHAR - char incompatibilty/conversion issue... Any suggestions on how to make this application work?

win32project.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

...

case WM_PAINT:
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

TCHAR szPath[128] = _T("");
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
gethostname(szPath, sizeof(szPath));
WSACleanup();

HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, szPath, _tcslen(szPath));

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;

...
```

Content of the stdafx.h included in win32project.cpp above:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// additional headers
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

Comment: *Looking at the error messages* -- Please post those error messages.  Also, a `TCHAR` is not a `char` if the app is Unicode.

Comment: Hard to know what to make of this. The code does not compile? The code compiles but does not behave as intended when run? For the former, read the error messages and think. For the latter, debug your program.

Comment: Seriously, we're living in the 21st century. Drop the `TCHAR` already. That was a helper macro to transition from the Windows 95 line to the Windows NT line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527.aspx) (or just look at the function declaration), you would see that `gethostname()` does not accept a  `TCHAR` output buffer, only a `char` buffer.  If you compile your project with Unicode enabled, `TCHAR` will map to `wchar_t`.  That is why your code fails to compile.  So change `TCHAR` to `char`, and use `TextOutA()` directly:

```
char szName[256] = "";
gethostname(szName, 256);
TextOutA(hdc, 10, 10, szName, strlen(szName));
```

Otherwise, consider using [`GetComputerName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295.aspx) instead:

```
TCHAR szName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = TEXT("");
DWORD dwLen = sizeof(szName) / sizeof(TCHAR);
if (!GetComputerName(szName, &dwLen)) dwLen = 0;
TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, szName, dwLen);
```

Or better, just drop `TCHAR` (do you really need to support Win9x/ME?) and just use `wchar_t` directly:

```
WCHAR szName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = L"";
DWORD dwLen = sizeof(szName) / sizeof(WCHAR);
if (!GetComputerNameW(szName, &dwLen)) dwLen = 0;
TextOutW(hdc, 10, 10, szName, dwLen);
```

Comment: Using only the code in your third suggestion / example inside the hdc painting section did the trick... Thanks! :)

Comment: Am a bit baffled by sizeof(WCHAR) though...Size of a datatype? I got a lot to learn.& figure out about this...

Comment: `sizeof()` is evaluated at compile-time and reports the byte size of its operand, which can be a type, variable, or expression. `WCHAR` is an alias for `wchar_t`, which is 2 bytes in size on Windows. `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` is 15. So `sizeof(szName)` is `(15 + 1) * 2) = 32` bytes in size. Divide that by `sizeof(WCHAR)=2` and you get 16, which is the max number of `WCHAR` elements that `szName` can hold, which is what `GetComputerName()` is looking for as input. `dwLen` could have also been initialized using `DWORD dwLen = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;` instead.